# Past simple in subordinating clause + perfect simple in main clause in the same sentence

Tags: tense-agreement

I'd like to ask if it is  wrong to say a sentence such as the following just because perfect and past tense is used together :

> As the operating system was *upgraded*, programmers have been finding new efficient ways to code it.

or should it be as follows :

> As the operating system was *upgraded*, programmers found new efficient ways to code it.

Comment: The meaning  is unclear. Maybe you could write a complete sentence. It should be *has* for a third person singular verb.

Comment: @AlanCarmack I edited it.

Comment: It isn't always *wrong* to mix tenses in a sentence, but you need to think about how they go together.  *was* implies this was in the past; *have found* is really talking about the present.  Mixing them up like this doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @stangdon I see your point. I edited the question to make it clear what I am trying to convey that  programmers  are always "finding new ways" for long time  naturally

Comment: I would use "since" instead of "as", to make the time relationship between the clauses more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second sentence

> As the operating system was upgraded, programmers found new efficient ways to code it.

is correct in the past, to place your first sentence in the present would be

> As the operating system *is* upgraded, programmers *are* finding new efficient ways to code it.

or alternatively in the past

> As the operating system was *being* upgraded, programmers *were* finding new efficient ways to code it.